# Laravel 'save()' for 'hasmany' Model

Tags: php, laravel-5

If I have a two models, with a hasMany relationship, so my `Car` hasmany `CarOwners`, I would like to use to use the `firstOrCreate` method to create a new `car`.

If I'm creating a new `car` then I need to create the first `CarOwner`too.

Without leveraging any laravel functionality, I would

1. create a new car,
2. get the ID of the new car object
3. create a new CarOwner, associating it with the recently created `car`

Isn't there a way to do this in one go? I can do the queries to *find* the CarOwners of the chosen car, but I can't see how to *save* across multiple tables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to laravel manual .if you already created a Model for them it would be like this

```
car->carOwners()->save($owners)
```

link https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: For 'hasMany' Model `->saveMany($owners)` should be used.